# Cross-Platform changes to Same-Platform in Fortnite BR, can I revert this?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

A few versions ago, in **Fortnite BR** on PC, near the middle-right, I see

> (Playing with strangers) Fill with:
> Same-Platform ||
> (Who you are against) Play with: Cross-Platform.

Now, after a few updates, it indicates:

> Fill with: Same-Platform || Play with: **Same-Platform**.

Whoa, that means, in updates, it somehow changed playing with different platforms to same platform(PC).

Can I change this, and how can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only play cross platform when there are people in your party that are on a different platform. So

- Duos: 2 PC, will always mean you get pitted against PC
- Duos: 1 PC + 1 PS4/Xbox will mean you get pitted cross play against other people playing on that console

NOTE: You can not play PS4 + Xbox as this is not permitted by Sony. All other options are possible.

Comment: I'd also like to add you can't actually change this option yourself. It will change automatically depending on the platforms of the people in your party.

Comment: Read my first sentence...